# Rails checkbox not storing correct value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, bit

I'm creating a form using Ruby Rails. It has a checkbox that when checked denotes the entry should be hidden (true or bit 1. vs false/bit 0), however, when I submit the checkbox I receive an error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column 'hidden_status' at row 1: INSERT INTO `entries` ( 'hidden_status') VALUES (x'30')
```

The schema for entries and `hidden_status` is:

```
t.binary "hidden_status", limit: 1
```

The checkbox is:

```
<%= newEntry.check_box(:hidden_status,{checked:true},1,0)%>
```

I suspect this has something to do with the datatype being "bit"? However I'm not sure as I'm new to Ruby Rails and from what I looked up BIT is the only way to do a boolean/true vs false value in SQL. Looks like the value is coming up as as `x'30'`. Not sure what that means.  Is there a way to allow the checkbox to capture 1 or 0?

Also, the parameters in the error shows that the value of the checkbox always returns `0` whether the box is checked or not.  Not sure if this is a separate issue or related to the error.

Comment: Show your controller side code

Answer (score 0):

MySQL still as of 2020 has not implemented a real boolean column type. But it does let you declare tables with BOOLEAN/BOOL:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    completed BOOLEAN
);
```

Whats actually created is a `tiny_int(1)` column. Although the current advice is to use a bit column I doubt the Rails adapter knows how to map this to booleans.

You can just create the migration in Rails like you would in a real grown-up database ([laughs in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-boolean.html)):

```
class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.boolean :completed

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

`schema.rb` will still list it as a boolean column as its an abstract polyglot representation of the database schema but MySQL will store it as `tiny_int(1)` and the database driver will take care of casting it to a boolean so you don't have to deal with 1 and 0 in Rails.

Comment: Thank you, this fixes the error. However the checkbox value is still showing as false in the parameter

Comment: Did you try removing all the additional parameters? `newEntry.check_box(:hidden_status)`. The default should really be set in the database instead.

Comment: Just tried that and still showing "0" whether checked or unchecked.